# Ubuntu Apache gives 404 error but index.php shows site css

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I am setting up an application on my ubuntu 18.04 localhost in a sub directory so the url looks like this: localhost/app-name.
The problem is that I keep getting an apache 404 error. I feel like I have tried everything between my default.conf and .htaccess. On the bright side if I type /index.php it atleast gives me a 404 page error from the site itself the site css. Here is my default.conf and .htaccess
**FOr what it's worth it was written on litten framework**

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app-name/


<Directory /var/www/html>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/eduTrac-SIS/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteBase /app-name
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /var/www/html/app-name/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Try your htaccess on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ also seem you don't make the file go to use index.php. That should be RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1 [NC,QSA,L]

Comment: Quite honestly it didn't do much for me. remember this is on my localhost

Comment: Yep it's localhost but it debug the data. Anyway the framework use the index.php to serve all pages right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figure it out. I too out all of the extras from the default.conf and let the .htaccess do it's thing along with some other changes within the framework. It all worked out.